# REACTJS giving the following error: TypeError: navigate.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am trying to implement a home page for my react.js website. My layout is fine and my code compiles without problems.

However when I click my button I am getting the following error on the website application: `TypeError: navigate.push is not a function` on the line that says     `navigate.push("/quiz")`

I am new to react and if anyone can help me I would be greatful!

Here is my code:

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Home.css";

const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const sendSubmit = () => {
    navigate.push("/quiz");
  };
  return (
    <Container className="content">
      <h1 id="quiz-title">Phishing Quiz</h1>
      <h2 class="question-text">
        Do you think you can beat our phishing quiz?
      </h2>
      <p className="description">
        {" "}
        There are many social engineering attacks on internet however not all of
        them are good enough to trick users. However there are some scams that
        are identical to original websites and usually most of the users get
        tricked by them.
      </p>
      <p className="description">
        Do you think you are smart enough to handle these attacks?
      </p>
      <p className="description">
        We are challenging you with our phishing quiz which will show you
        examples of really good social engineering attacks on internet. We hope
        you can pass!
      </p>
      <p>""</p>
      <Button
        className="button"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        size="large"
        onClick={sendSubmit}
      >
        Start Quiz
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Which version of react-router-dom is used? if its v5 you can use import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"; insted of your useNavigate

Comment: @Mahesh When I try using useHistory it gives me the following error: `Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.` Also my version is  6.0.2 , `react-router-dom@6.0.2`.

Comment: Ok in v6 useHistory is replaced by useNavigate so you can check with below code 

    import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate('/quiz');

Comment: @Mahesh Can I call `navigate('/home') `inside onClick={}

Comment: insted of navigate.push("/quiz"); you can use navigate("/quiz");

Comment: @Mahesh Works perfectly fine! Thank you so much! If you can submit your code as an answer I can mark it as a solution :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

can check with below code

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and inside Home arrow function

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const sendSubmit = () => {
    navigate("/quiz");
};
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me but I don't get why it's so hard to find this info of having to use navigate(...) instead of navigate.push(...). Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

issued a push your code must look like this:

```
const Home = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();

// delete push
const sendSubmit = () => {
navigate("/quiz");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions as we are using `useHistory` hook, we are using push functions

```
const history = useHistory()
   const fun = () => { history.push('/link')
 }
```

Now after upgrading react we are using useNavigate() hook and we can keep link directly in params like below:

```
const naviagte = useNavigate()
   const fun = () => { navigate('/link')
 }
```